# diferencia entre un parámetro,una constante y una variable local y global

Tags: python

Me podrían decir algún ejemplo explicando qué es un parámetro,una constante y una variable local y global y sus diferencias

si es posible con ejemplos en Python, tengan en cuenta también que soy muy novato en el ámbito de la programación

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Este sitio es más para preguntas concretas de una duda específica. Aquí se suele exponer códigos de ejemplo para resolver una duda o error muy particular. Te sugiero que busques la información que necesitas en google, que te puede ayudar mucho más que aquí sobre lo que preguntas y cuando tengas una duda más particular regresar aquí. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Variable**

Es quien almacena un valor, puede ser un número (int o float), una cadena de texto (string), una función, una instancia de una clase, una list/dictionary comprehension, y demás. (Ahorita no te preocupes de estos dos últimos, los entenderás luego ;) )

**Variable global**

Es toda variable que está definida 'sola', o que está fuera de cualquier función. Es decir, que la puedes acceder desde cualquier función/método. Ej:

```
soy_global = 'Queso'

def soy_funcion():
    #cosas de funcion
```

**Variable local**

Es toda aquella que sólo existe en la función o método que fue declarada. No puede ser usada fuera de ese **ámbito** (llamado scope en inglés). Ej:

```
def saludar_nombre():
    soy_local = 'Pepe'
    print('Hola ' + soy_local)
```

Si intentas ocupar `soy_local` fuera de la función en que fue declarada te dará un error, porque sólo está declarada en el scope local de la función.

**Parámetro**

Variable que le "mandas" a una función/clase/método. Ej:

```
# Utilizando la función saludar_nombre de arriba
def saludar_nombre(nombre):
    nombre_persona = nombre
    print('Hola ' + nombre_persona)

# Aquí llamamos a la función y le pasamos un nombre que querramos
saludar_nombre('Salazar')
# Salida: Hola Salazar
```

**Argumento**

Si tomamos de ejemplo la función de ejemplo `saludar_nombre`, en la declaración de función la parte que está dentro de paréntesis es el argumento, osea es quien recibe los parámetros que se le mandaron.
Puede tener absolutamente cualquier nombre que quieras, sin embargo, es muy recomendado que se ocupe un nombre relacionado al dato que se está recibiendo.

Tienes que buscar más tutoriales en Youtube y leer la documentación oficial https://docs.python.org/3/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Es una pregunta muy amplia. Pero como lo dice la palabra, la diferencia entre variable y constante es que la variable es un dato dinámico, que puede ser modificado por el usuario (input) o por el programa mismo. En cambio una constante es un dato que permanece inmutable. Por ej: IDIOMA = es

Local o Global es el ámbito en que la variable o constante existe.

Te recomiendo Googlearlo para obtener info más precisa.
Además, en este tipo de foros, este tipo de preguntas muy amplias te dan reputación negativa.