# ¿Como construyo una función que transforme un entero sin importar su nombre?

Tags: python

En este ejemplo al estar el numero definido por un nombre sale automático:

```
numero=1

def sumaruno():
    numerosumado=numero+1
    return(numerosumado)

print(sumaruno())
```

¿Pero como hago que la función pueda transformar cualquier número independientemente de su nombre?
(Fijaos bien que en la función la palabra "numero" esta definida y la función puede operar con ella)

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres, te podrías explicar mejor  o aportar mas información?

Comment: A que nombre te refieres???  Yo solo veo variables aquí

Comment: Pasa el número como parámetro de la función. Para eso son los parámetros.

Answer (score 1):

Tu ejemplo está usando la función, pero al mismo está trabajando con una variable del ámbito global. Esto no es una buena práctica ni un buen diseño de programa.

Leer sobre el [ámbito de las variables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/123410/80870)

```
def sumaruno(x):
    numerosumado = x + 1
    return(numerosumado)

numero = 1
otronum = 25
datos = [5, 6, 7]

resultado = sumaruno(numero)
print(resultado) # Res: 2

# Tambien se puede invocar la función directamente
print(sumaruno(otronum)) # Res: 26
print(sumaruno(5)) # Res: 6
print(sumaruno(True)) # Res: 2

# Se puede aplicar la funcion a cada elemento de una estructura:
datos_modificados = list(map(sumaruno, datos))
print(datos_modificados) # Res: [6, 7, 8]
```

Como puedes notar, la variable local `x` en la función `sumaruno` toma el valor que le pases en la llamada, se procesa dentro de la función de forma aislada al resto del programa y luego se retorna el valor procesado a donde fue llamada.